# Will this tube accelerate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image: Sealed tube]

My question relates to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/623514/is-the-pressure-uniform-across-a-gas-container-having-a-tempeature-gradient) and more specifically an answer (by 'oliver') it received.

*A sealed tube is heated at one end and cooled at the opposite end. The OP wanted to know whether there's a pressure gradient in the tube.*

The question itself doesn't particularly interest me but how 'oliver' set out proving there's no such gradient does. Basically he contends that:

> If the pressure was higher on the hot end than on the cold end, the
> total force would also be higher on the hot end than on the cold end,
> and hence, the container would accelerate without external directed
> force being applied, which would contradict momentum conservation.

So he concludes that no acceleration means no pressure gradient ($P_H=P_C$).

I find that hard to comprehend. There are no external forces and no changes of momentum (Ok, maybe just a little at the start of the heating/cooling)

It reminds me of a man in a small sloop (dinghy). The man pushes on the bow ($F_B$) and the stern ($F_S$). If $F_B>F_S$ would the sloop move? No, of course not.

[image: Man in sloop]

So how can we prove 'oliver' is right (or wrong)?

Comment: Why do you think there should be (even could be) a pressure gradient? A temperature gradient, sure, but gas molecules are not being held in place to allow the pressure to rise in part of it. Instead, there will be a mass (particle density) gradient established, keeping the pressure constant.

Comment: @JonCuster Where do I intimate there is such a pressure gradient? I'm, as stated, not interested in *that* question but rather in 'oliver's' method for proving that there's no such gradient. He claims there would be acceleration **IF** there was such a gradient. I find that a questionable proposition.

Comment: Say there is an explosion at $P_H$ causing a pressure wave to propagate wouldn't it hit the left wall first causing the container to move left and then right? This is a really interesting problem because energy _is_ added to the system.

Comment: @JAlex I was initially going to include your example (explosion in the LHS of the tube). But I have little doubt that acceleration would take place because there's change in momentum. It's like running from one end of the sloop to the other. Momentum conservation would demand movement by the sloop.

Comment: Is this tube horizontal or vertical stated? There are could be convection and pressure gradient as well. But sum of force from the pressure and viscous force could be equal zero if we suggest  that tube is not fixed.

Comment: I think if the pressure gradient is static, there will be a force on the tube. One can integrate the diagonal component of the stress tensor in the direction parallel to the pressure gradient over the surface of the tube. (a) This quantity will be non-zero because of the pressure gradient, (b) this quantity measures the net flow of momentum in this direction. Combining a and b, there will have to be a net force. The key assumption is that the gradient is *static* -- that can only happen if there is something pushing the air in the tube (providing the force). Else, you'll get a sloshing wave.

Comment: The temperature difference will definitely produce a circulating convective gas flow in the tube.  A flow necessarily requires a pressure difference, and even though that pressure difference is very small, it will still be there due to differences in gas density at each end of the tube.

Comment: A difference in density does not automatically mean a difference in pressure. Don’t forget the temperature gradient there also.